# how to remove element from 4D matlab matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Hi I have the following 4D matrix

```
for idx_number_panels = 1:length(number_panels) % range of PV panel units examined

for number_turbines = 0:2 % range of wind turbine units examined

    for number_batteries = 1:10 % range of battery units examined


        for h=2:25 %# hours

            for d = 1:number_of_days %# which day

                n = h + 24*(d-1);
                % hourly_deficit_1(...,..., h, d)= Demand(n)-(PV_supply(n)... %


                hourly_total_RES(idx_number_panels,number_turbines + 1,number_batteries, h,d)
```

I want to remove the entire row every 24 rows from the above 4D matrix and thus resize the matrix. Is this possible and how can it be done since the documentation doesn't seem to help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make a vector of all the row indices you want to keep
2. Index just those rows of hourly_total_RES and assign back to hourly_total_RES.

   trashidx = 1:24:idx_number_panels;

   keepidx = setdiff(1:idx_number_panels, trashidx);

   hourly_total_RES = hourly_total_RES(keepidx,:,:,:);

And I don't know why the above isn't formatting as code....

Comment: so you are suggesting one "trashidx" vector for each of the dimensions? Will the 1:24:idx_number_panels apply for one row every 24 rows? i.e 1st, 25th, 49th etc?

Comment: From your above code, I thought the 4D matrix you were referring to was hourly_total_RES and the rows are indexed by idx_number_panels. But this being your code, if you say 1:24:h then so be it. Also, If you do this in MATLAB console you will see that:

1:24:100

ans =

     1    25    49    73    97